# How to get hierarchical number of custom taxanomy

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, tax-query

I have custom taxonomy some thing like :

- Item - A

  - Item A-1
  - Item A-2

    - Item A-2-1
    - Item A-2-2

Now i want to get what is the number of hierarchical number of Item A-2, if we start from 0 it should be 1 and so on..

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_ancestors()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors) to get an array of parents, which you can then count.

```
$term_id = 42;
$ancestors = get_ancestors( $term_id, 'category' );
if( ! empty( $ancestors ) ){
    echo count( $ancestors );
}
```